# How to scale background-image to fit responsive div

Tags: html, css, background, responsive-design, background-image

I'm trying to make a "Did you know?" fixed div in the right corner. Unfortunately after 3 hours of testing many solutions still can't find correct one. As you can see on this fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/dq8f3d4p/ I can't make the background fit the div.

Both: `background-size: cover;` and `background-size: 100%;` seems not to work properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, you are overwriting `background-size` with the shorthand `background` property :

```
.dyk{
    position: fixed;
    z-index:2;
    width: 17.26%;
    height: 11%;
    left: 80%;
    top: 80%;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/gxp9iDV.png);
}
```

Changing it to `background-image` property will cause the image to stretch to 100% size.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for `background-size:contain;`, Which is usually the best pick, however, in your case the image proportions and the div's proportions are not the the same so I would recommend using `background-size: 100% 100%;`.

```
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/gxp9iDV.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dq8f3d4p/3/)

**Notes:**

1. background-size is supported by IE9+
2. Use `contain` if you don't want your image to get streched.

Answer (score -1):

put the image inside you div and then fix the div to bottom right

```
<div class="dyk">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/gxp9iDV.png"></img>
</div>

.dyk{
    position: fixed;
    z-index:2;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```